# Suppose $p \mid |G|$ and let $H \leq G$ be a $p$-group. Show that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups which contain $H$ is congruent to $1 \pmod{p}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Question**: Suppose $p \mid |G|$ and let $H \leq G$ be a $p$-group. Show that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups which contain $H$ is congruent to $1 \pmod{p}$.

**My Work**: I know that the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups are congruent to $1 \pmod{p}$. To show the result, it suffices to show that every $H \leq G$ $p$-group is contained in one and only one Sylow-$p$ subgroup. I am not sure how to prove the only one part for this. Any hints.

Comment: You went a bit too far. A $p$-group might be contained in more than one $p$-Sylow subgroup. Sylow groups can have a nontrivial intersection.

Comment: @Mark Then, how do I solve this question?

Comment: First, if $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup and $H$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ then $H\cap P=H\cap N_G(P)$, pretty sure that was already proved on this forum. So $H\leq P$ iff $H\leq N_G(P)$. Now define an action of $H$ on $Syl_p(G)$ by conjugation. The Sylow groups which contain $H$ are exactly the Sylow groups which have orbit of size $1$. The orbits of the other Sylow groups have size which is divisible by $p$. Now use the fact that $n_p\equiv 1$(mod $p$).

Comment: @Mark I think I understand what to do now. Can you direct me to the proof of the result in the comment?

Comment: You mean that $H\cap P=H\cap N_G(P)$? One inclusion is trivial. For the converse, note that $H\cap N_G(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$, and so contained in a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $N_G(P)$. But note that $P$ is a normal Sylow subgroup of $N_G(P)$, and hence the unique Sylow subgroup of $N_G(P)$. If so, we must have $H\cap N_G(P)\leq P$, which gives the result.

Comment: @Mark Can you explain this part: The Sylow groups which contain $H$
 are exactly the Sylow groups which have orbit of size $1$. The orbits of the other Sylow groups have size which is divisible by $p$. Now use the fact that $n \equiv \pmod{n}$. 
n
p
≡
1
(mod 
p
).

Comment: The size of each orbit is a power of $p$, because $H$ is a $p$-group. So the size of an orbit is not divisible by $p$ exactly when it has size $1$. I'll leave you the simple verification that the orbit of $P$ has size $1$ iff $H\leq N_G(P)$, and this happens iff $H\leq P$ by what I proved in the previous comment. And now compute the number of orbits of size $1$ modulo $p$.

Comment: @Mark Can you please write a detailed answer?

Comment: I wrote pretty much everything. Which part is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

As I've explained in the comments, for each Sylow $p$-subgroup $P\leq G$ we have $H\cap P=H\cap N_G(P)$. It immediately follows that $H\leq P$ if and only if $H\leq N_G(P)$.

Define an action of $H$ on $Syl_p(G)$ by conjugation. Let $X\subseteq Syl_p(G)$ the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups which contain $H$. Note that $P\in X$ if and only if the orbit of $P$ has size $1$. Indeed, if $P\in X$ then $H\leq P$ and then clearly $hPh^{-1}=P$ for all $h\in H$, and so the orbit of $P$ has size $1$. Conversely, if the orbit of $P$ has size $1$ then $hPh^{-1}=P$ for all $h\in H$, and so $H\leq N_G(P)$. As we observed earlier, this implies $H\leq P$, i.e $P\in X$.

Since $H$ is a $p$-group, the cardinality of each orbit is a power of $p$. If so, the orbit of each element $P\notin X$ has cardinality $p^a$ for some $a\geq 1$, and so divisible by $p$. Since $Syl_p(G)$ is the disjoint union of the orbits, we deduce:

$|Syl_p(G)|\equiv |X|$ (mod $p$)

On the other hand, by the Sylow theorems we have $|Syl_p(G)|\equiv 1$ (mod $p$). The result follows.